# Create a TV specific layout with jetpack compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

Lets say I have a layout that would apply phones/tablets, now I want to change how this UI would display on TV's only to be more remote friendly.

normally in the View based layouts I would create a layout folder `layout-television` or in some instances `layout-tvdpi`

but with jetpack compose from what I can tell there are only three different window sizes to work with for creating different types of layouts

```
WindowWidthSizeClass.Compact
WindowWidthSizeClass.Medium
WindowWidthSizeClass.Expanded
```

Where TV would fall under Expanded but also tablets/desktop could fall under that too I believe.

Is there a way to have the app display a UI specific for TV's in compose like there is for the normal view based layouts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`hasSystemFeature()` on `PackageManager`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager#hasSystemFeature(java.lang.String)), looking for [`FEATURE_LEANBACK`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager#FEATURE_LEANBACK), for those cases where you really do have composables that are usable on TVs and mobile devices.

I say "really do", because [TV Compose](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/tv) has its own design system, one that conflicts in composable names with Compose Material and Compose Material3. TV Compose has great D-pad support, even in its alpha state. However, the conflicting composables means having TV Compose code in the same module as mobile Compose UI code might suck. Plus, I don't anticipate very many composables working all that well on both mobile and TV, just because the user interactions and font sizes are so different.

Personally, if I were doing a single app for both mobile and TV, based on what I know, I'd use TV Compose, with separate modules for the mobile and TV UIs. They might share a common module for things that do work out for being shareable. Then, I'd either have two separate launcher activities (one mobile, one TV) or have the single launcher activity route to each form factor's UI via `FEATURE_LEANBACK` (or possibly `FEATURE_TELEVISION`, in case for some reason Amazon Fire TV blew off the `FEATURE_LEANBACK` switch with API Level 21).

If you want to avoid TV Compose and try handling the D-pad input yourself, you might be able to reduce the number of modules. For me, modules are easy compared to fussing with D-pad input.